# CI Session not working in error views

Tags: codeigniter, session, view

I am trying to set session in views/errors/html/error_404.php session library already load in autoload file.

```
$tech_error = array('is_error_404' => 'yes','is_error_404_data' => $content);
$this->session->set_userdata($tech_error);
```

Its throwing error, `Fatal error: Call to a member function set_userdata() on null`

can't we access CodeIgniter session in error views?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$ci = & get_instance(); 
$ci->session->set_data('is_error_404','yes');
$ci->session->set_data('is_error_404_data',$content);
```

then retrieve each session data ? using

```
$this->session->userdata('is_error_404');
```

Comment: not working, it not allow to use Codeigniter session in error views